# Answers and comments

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should one do when one's question has been answered in the comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments)

What do you do when you see a question that has no answer but is answered in a comment? I'm asking because even though I know the question has already technically been answered isn't there some sort of benefit to closing out the question if only so it doesn't get bumped to the front page by the "community bot"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I encounter such questions, particularly if they're old, I'll copy/paste the comments that answer the question into a CW answer.  If the comments only sort-of answer the question or if I can otherwise write a better answer (even if it's based on the comment-answer(s)), I'd do that instead.